# Tools/frameworks for managing app version on clients

Tags: java, deployment, versioning, auto-update

We have a Java application which is roughly composed of a interfaceless service and a web application.

As the number of installed instances of our app grows, we feel the urgent need to manage what version is installed on which client and, if possible somehow, automate the update process, specially bug fix updates.

Anyone have suggestions on tools or frameworks or even best practices articles that might help us with this?

I know it's a challenging problem, and I barely believe there will be something that is a magical answer.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Jonathas

Answer (score 0):

This can often be done with a "phone home" sort of a poll from the client application, depending on what resources are needed. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930781/versioning-in-device-server-development) for a more general solution.